# Check whether two indicators are the same

Tags: r, data.table, grouping, indicator

I am given a large data table with two indicators `ind1` and `ind2` with possible repetitions. E.g.

```
 set.seed(1)
 ind1 <- sample(1:3,1000, replace=TRUE )
 ind2 <- c("a","b","c")[ind1]

 dt <- data.table(ind1=ind1, ind2=ind2)
```

I would like now to check, whether These two indicators group the data the same way, i.e.

two rows have the same indicator `ind1` if and only if they also the same indicator `ind2`. In the above example, this would be the case by construction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply group by `ind2` and count distinct `ind1` or vice-versa. If any count > 1 then they don't group the data in the same way. Here's a way with base R -

```
any(with(dt, ave(ind1, ind2, FUN = function(x) length(unique(x)))) > 1)

[1] FALSE # means ind1 and ind2 group the data in same way
```

Alternatively, you can check if all count == 1 using `all` if that's easier to interpret -

```
all(with(dt, ave(ind1, ind2, FUN = function(x) length(unique(x)))) == 1)

[1] TRUE # means ind1 and ind2 group the data in same way
```

Answer (score 3):

My instinct would be to use .GRP as in @IceCreamToucan's answer, but another way is to drop duplicates jointly for the two columns, and then check for duplicates in each column separately:

```
# data.table
unique(dt[, c("ind1", "ind2")])[, !(anyDuplicated(ind1) || anyDuplicated(ind2))]

# base, with df = data.frame(dt)
with(unique(df[, c("ind1", "ind2")]), !(anyDuplicated(ind1) || anyDuplicated(ind2)))
```

I tried various benchmarks, but don't see any clear results except, surprisingly, that the timing between the two options above almost always heavily favors data.table.

Example with parameters for #rows and #groups:

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)

ng = 150
n = 1e6
set.seed(1)
ind1 <- sample(1:ng, n, replace=TRUE )
ind2 <- -ind1

dt <- data.table(ind1=ind1, ind2=ind2)
df = data.frame(dt)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(times = 3L,
grp = dt[,  g1 := .GRP, ind1][, g2 := .GRP, ind2][, all(g1 == g2)], 
uniques = dt[, uniqueN(ind2), ind1][, all(V1 == 1)],
shreet = with(dt, max(tapply(ind1, ind2, function(x) length(unique(x))))) == 1L,
shreep = with(dt, tapply(ind1, ind2, . %>% unique %>% length)) %>% max %>% equals(1L),
another = unique(dt[, c("ind1", "ind2")])[, !(anyDuplicated(ind1) || anyDuplicated(ind2))],
banother = with(unique(df[, c("ind1", "ind2")]), !(anyDuplicated(ind1) || anyDuplicated(ind2)))
)
```

Results:

```
Unit: milliseconds
     expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval
      grp   31.89250   34.92348   46.06510   37.95446   53.15140   68.34833     3
  uniques   32.82520   34.36808   36.32377   35.91097   38.07306   40.23515     3
   shreet   38.26046   38.35256   44.37116   38.44467   47.42650   56.40834     3
   shreep   43.37336   98.56367  145.38600  153.75399  196.39231  239.03064     3
  another   14.47064   31.42879   88.20134   48.38694  125.06669  201.74643     3
 banother 1338.14070 1427.35481 1658.08404 1516.56893 1818.05572 2119.54251     3
```

Comment: i consistently get `another` to be faster regardless of using `microbenchmark` or `bench::mark`. Using `Win 7 R-3.5.1 x64 data.table 1.12.2, DTthreads=4, 16GB RAM`

Comment: I get ```another``` as the fastest as well. If ```uniques``` uses ```unique(length(ind1))```, it's second place for me by a significant margin. I have 2 core / 4 thread.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a numeric group index with both vars and check that they're equal for all rows.

This will add the two group indices to the table as well as check for equality, but you can remove the columns after if needed

```
dt[,  g1 := .GRP, ind1][, g2 := .GRP, ind2][, all(g1 == g2)]
#[1] TRUE
```

Edit: Shree's unique-counting idea is better. See below for data.table implementation

Edit2: Also see comments for other solutions

```
dt[, uniqueN(ind2), ind1][, all(V1 == 1)]
#[1] TRUE
```

Benchmark with table having 1e7 rows and 10 groups, represented with two equivalent columns

```
set.seed(1)
ind1 <- sample(1:10,1e7, replace=TRUE )
ind2 <- c("a","b","c")[ind1]

dt <- data.table(ind1=ind1, ind2=ind2)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
grp = dt[,  g1 := .GRP, ind1][, g2 := .GRP, ind2][, all(g1 == g2)], 
uniques = dt[, uniqueN(ind2), ind1][, all(V1 == 1)]
)

# Unit: milliseconds
#     expr      min       lq    mean   median       uq       max neval cld
#      grp 727.9489 838.2190 918.280 879.1036 971.3982 1542.9655   100   b
#  uniques 472.1311 502.1327 529.581 526.5357 540.5406  723.5078   100  a
```

Comment: Another: `unique(dt[, c("ind1", "ind2")])[, !(anyDuplicated(ind1) || anyDuplicated(ind2))]`... and another variant of Shree's, I think: `with(dt, max(tapply(ind1, ind2, function(x) length(unique(x))))) == 1L`

Comment: Fyi, I find uniques is very bad if I scale the problem up: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/46781006#46781006

Comment: For me, if I change 1e4 to 1e6 in that linked benchmark, it reverses so that the "uniques" option is better than all but the "another" option. I'd say it's worth posting this info and those other approaches as a separate answer.

Comment: Okay, yeah, I've been tweaking n & ng parameters since my prior comment and see the comparisons going every way. Will post another answer, thanks

Comment: ```unique(length(ind2))``` is about twice as fast as ```uniqueN(ind2)```.